# grouping a list of lists by their first element

Tags: haskell, group-by

I am trying to learn Haskell on my spare time by solving ProjectEuler problems, and when I hit problem 5 I ended up trying to group a list of lists by their first element. Below is an example of the behaviour I want:

Input:

```
[[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [3, 3]]`
```

Output:

```
[[[2], [2, 2]], [[3], [3, 3]], [[5]], [[7]]]
```

To do this, I wrote the following code

```
import Data.List (groupBy)

factors = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [3, 3]]
groupedFactors = 
    let comp x y = (head x) == (head y)
    in groupBy comp factors
```

However, the result of the above code is the following list

```
[[[2]],[[3]],[[2,2]],[[5]],[[7]],[[3,3]]]
```

I tried to debug this, so I wrote the following code in GHCI:

```
factors = [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [3, 3]]
comp x y = (head x) == (head y)
comp (factors!!0) (factors!!2)
```

Which yielded `True`, comparing the fourth element yielded `False`, as expected.

I want to finish by saying that I can, of course, solve the problem at hand with another methodology, but I am keen on finding out what's happening here. It is more important for me to understand why I get this behaviour than how to fix it (although, I won't say no to a solution as well).

Comment: Please be aware that the purpose of Project Euler is to encourage people to think and learn so publishing the solution or working code would render this process useless.

Comment: AS a hint, `groupBy` function groups elements on a row. So `groupBy (==) [1,1, 2,3]` returns `[[1,1], [2], [3]]` whereas `groupBy (==) [1, 2, 1,3]` returns `[[1], [2], [1], [3]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's note that instead of writing your explicitly named `comp`, it's easier to use the [`on` combinator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Function> groupBy ((==)`on`head) [[2], [2,2], [3], [3,5]] 
[[[2],[2,2]],[[3],[3,5]]]
```

Now, the `group`* functions always only cluster together elements that are already adjacent in the list.

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Function> group "aaabac"
["aaa","b","a","c"]
```

The reason is that this can be done in *O*(*n*) time and lazily, whereas gathering elements from anywhere in the list given only an equality predicate would be O(*n*²). To make that *efficient*, the usual way to to first *sort* the list, which brings grouping-candidates together in only O(*n*·log *n*) time.

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Function> group $ sort "aaabac"
["aaaa","b","c"]
```

So for your example, this would be

```
> groupBy ((==)`on`head) $ sortBy (compare`on`head) [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [3, 3]]
[[[2],[2,2]],[[3],[3,3]],[[5]],[[7]]]
```

This can be simplified by using the `sortOn` function, which already has the pre-mapping built in:

```
> groupBy ((==)`on`head) $ sortOn head [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [3, 3]]
[[[2],[2,2]],[[3],[3,3]],[[5]],[[7]]]
```

or even shorter with [`groupSortOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6.13/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:groupSortOn) from the `extra` package, which has it all in one function:

```
Prelude Data.List.Extra> groupSortOn head [[2], [3], [2, 2], [5], [7], [3, 3]]
[[[2],[2,2]],[[3],[3,3]],[[5]],[[7]]]
```

Since I generally discourage the use of `head`, I would suggest you consider to use `take 1` in its stead.